# Почему не удается создать сегмент разделяемой памяти?

Tags: php

Использую блоки разделяемой памяти, ключом в процессе является ид строки из базы данных. При некоторых ключах получаю ошибку

> shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment

Например, когда вызываю

> shmop_open(63849, 'c', 0755, 1000)

или

> shmop_open(63850, 'c', 0755, 1000)

но сегмент создается при вызове с другими ключами - 63848 и менее или 63851 и более. Что может быть не так конкретно с этими значениями?

Всю информацию предоставлю для решения.

Comment: я бы запустил `ipcs -m` (это в случае линукса) и посмотрел, а никто случайно этот ключ не занял. Вполне возможно, что другой пользователь (рут) его держит.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Запустил скрипт от рута, тот и занял ключ. Иной юзер не смог получить доступ.